# The limit of a divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R_+}$ be a real positive sequence such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
a_n
=\infty
$$
a
I would like to konw if is it true that:

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}
\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty
a_n
=0
$$

Thanks.

Comment: As already shown, this is not true, however you have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\neq \infty\Rightarrow \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n=0$ is that what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks @JürgMerlinSpaak i understood the ansewer

Comment: Maybe you can think variations. I hope that next have mathematical meaning: *Exercise 1.* Provide a characterization (on the size of $|a_n|$) of those sequences $a_n's$ such that having $\sum a_n=\infty$ satisfy $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\mu(n)a_n$ is finite, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function. *Exercise 2.* Provide a characterization of sequences $a_n's$ such that having $\sum a_n=\infty$ satisfy that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(g(k)\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n\right)$ is finite, where $g(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$. I don't know if these are well known/interestings. Good luck.

Comment: thanks @user243301 i will think about it, it seems interesting

Comment: I believe that the *Exercise 1* should be related with the Prime Number Theorem. On the other hand my comment is to encourage to you to ask from all your abilities/skills, not only about your knowledges, I am saying also involving your imagination or creativity. Is not required a response of this comment, good week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Take $a_n=n$. Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n=\infty$$

for all $k\in\Bbb N$. Actually this is *the rule* and no exception. For general $a_n$ we have

$$\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\sum_{n=1}^k a_n=\infty-\sum_{n=1}^k a_n = \infty$$

because the latter sum is a finite number.

Comment: there i something i don't understand in all 3 answer because you don't consider the limit, in @M. Winter ansewr if you do the limit you get $\infty -\infty$

Comment: @Matey Because the sum is divergent for all $k$ it does not matter if you include the limit: $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\infty=\infty$$.

Comment: @Matey You make the mistake of splitting the limit where it is not appropriate. You want to compute $\lim (\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\sum_{n=1}^ka_n)$ but you rearrange it to $\lim \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n - \lim \sum_{n=1}^ka_n$ which gives you $\infty-\infty.$ But this is not a valid action. You cannot split a sum inside a limes when it diverges.

Comment: ok @M. Winter i understood thanks

Answer (score 6):

No.  If
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
a_n
=\infty
$$
then
$$
\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty
a_n
=\infty
$$
for all $k$.  Thus,
$$
\lim_{k \to 
\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty
a_n
=0
$$
is false.

Comment: thanks @GEdgar now i understood

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $a_n=1$ for each natural $n$. Indeed, you can even take $a_n=\frac1n$, and this exemple shows that your statement is false even if we assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.